# How to make a preloader with load external file?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, preloader

I am currently working with Flex 4. I successfully use custom preloader by  s:application ... preloader="path"..., but i want the preloader to load external file as well, can it do that? How can i call the variables in the preloader?

Thanks for everyone has a look at my question.

Comment: Do you loading external file while your swf is still loading and want to show total progress?

Comment: Yes, that would be great... Can you provide me the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not a readymade solution, but the idea.
If you have simple preloader working, you should know how many bytes it has to load. To load external file, create `Loader`. Now you have bytesTotal from preloader and bytesTotal from Loader via ProgressEvents from them. To compute percents properly, you need to use sum of bytesLoaded and sum of bytesTotal.